# "....of the deepest eye", meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, idioms

I have seen phrases like these:

> - All the villains of the deepest eye.
> - Allison was a religious bigot of the deepest eye.

What does it mean? Is it something like "to the greatest extent"?

Comment: I think I've found where you are quoting these from (the first is lyrics, the second is a quote by alex ferdinand.  But please confirm this by adding the links to the sources of these quotes to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It means "most black" and by extension "most evil".  It is a rare expression, but was perhaps more common 100 years ago.

It seems to be alluding to the notion that the colour black is evil, and the pupil of the eye is deep black.  It was also formally used to just mean "black", both as a simple reference to the colour and in reference to the colour of people's skin.  The African American astronomer Benjamin Banneker said  "I am of the African race, and in the color which is natural to them of the deepest eye..."

It's such a rare phrase, that I don't think I'd understand it without context.  I've found examples of it being taught in books on English published in India alongside other examples of highly dated "casual" expressions. This isn't an expression you need to learn to speak good English.

Comment: Huh.  I'd have assumed it was a misprint for "deepest dye."

Comment: I hadn't heard it before, but a little research showed that it was appearing too often to be a misprint.